# Passing a function pointer with void pointer argument to a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have a function pointer in a structure, with a void* argument.
I would like to pass this function to another one, but I get compilation errors...

This is the function declaration in the structure:

```
void (*on_click)(void *);
```

And this is how I pass the function pointer to my function, where box is a structure:

```
but1 = create_button(posbut, "test", BUTTON_DEF, &on_click((void *)box));
```

I have the error: cannot convert to a pointer type, and lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand on this line.

Thanks !

Comment: You should show the declaration of `create_button`. Also, if that is a declaration in a structure, then you cannot just write `on_click`, you have to use a structure access operator with a structure variable

Comment: `&on_click((void *)box)` is wrong because `on_click((void *)box)` is not a function, it's a function call. It should be `&on_click` (or just `on_click` for short).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pass the function pointer like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
but1 = create_button(posbut, "test", BUTTON_DEF, on_click);
```

I don't know which framework you are using, so I don't know if there are other arguments that you have to pass to `create_button`, but most propbably `create_button` will be the one that calls the function pointer with the correct argument.

---

**fotenotes**

provided that the last argument of `create_button` is a `void (*callback)(void*)`